# Php functions showing wrong output

Tags: php, mysql, function

I have a small function that shows the output  from Database values

but the error is I put the condition that if the function output value is empty then show N/A  and if it is not empty then sow the database value
here is the function

```
function ClientCompDesignation($ClientDesignation,$ClientCompany){
    include "config/dbcon.php";
    $SessionClientID=$_SESSION['uid'];
    $ClientCDQuery="SELECT ClientCompany,ClientDesignation FROM ClientLogin WHERE ClientID='$SessionClientID'";
    $CLaCDQueryRun=mysqli_query($con,$ClientCDQuery);
    $CLCDRecordFetch=mysqli_fetch_assoc($CLaCDQueryRun);
    $ClientDesignation=$CLCDRecordFetch['ClientDesignation'];
    $ClientCompany=$CLCDRecordFetch['ClientCompany'];
    echo $ClientDesignation. ' - ' .$ClientCompany;
}
```

Here is the how i am displaying in HTML

```
<p class="mb-0 text-secondary"><?php if(ClientAddress($clientCity,$ClientCountry)==""){
    echo "N/A";
}
else {
    echo ClientAddress($clientCity,$ClientCountry);
}
?>
</p>
```

the problem is even when there is value in database it shows the N/A

this is the output

```
Sr. UI/UX Designer - IntraDevelopersN/A
```

please help in this

Comment: The function doesn't return anything, it echoes the output itself. Change `echo` in the client to `return`.

Comment: The function can never return an empty string. Even if both variables are empty, it returns `' - '`

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several issues here:

1. the function you have shown is `ClientCompDesignation`, not `ClientAddress`
2. assuming the same code pattern, you're echoing information in the called function, not returning it.
3. `ClientAddress` sometimes gets called twice - call your function *once* and assign the result to a variable that is tested in the `if` branch.